# What is the explanation of this Cast to Generic behaviour?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

```cs
public interface IBaseUiItem
{}

public interface IButton : IBaseUiItem
{}

public class ControlBase : IBaseUiItem
{}

public class Button : ControlBase, IButton
{}

public I GetOne<I>() where I : IBaseUiItem
{
     return (I)(new Button());
}

public I GetTwo<I>() where I : IBaseUiItem
{
     object f = new Button();
     return (I)f;
}
```

In the above why GetOne() doesn't compile, but the GetTwo() does?
In other words why the error in the first case is "Connot convert type Button to I"

I tried using "as" operator to see if it makes difference (without luck of course).
I guess, the GetOne cannot be compiled because saves you from a creation of an instance (new Button) that might not implement the interface type  you supply to the method.
And also I understand the "object" being so general makes it a possible candidate for casting to any type.
And finally, the fact that there is no special interface-obtaining-operator doesn't allow the compiler to make proper usage of the generic, no matter if it is an "interface generic" and not "type generic".

Comment: because you have defined f as 'object' type which is not an IBaseUiItem so the cast won't work.  Define it as a Button type and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In other words why the error in the first case is "Cannot convert type Button to I"

Because `I` is not guaranteed to be `Button` (or any interface which inherits `IBaseUiItem` and is implemented by `Button`) i.e. compiler prevents calls such as:

```cs
public class NotAButton : ControlBase, IButton {}

var x = GetOne<NotAButton>();
```

using `object` as intermediate type disables this compiler check (as explicit conversion [from `object` and `dynamic` to any other *reference_type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1035-explicit-reference-conversions)) and you will get [runtime error](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAcRgwBUB3CAHgDkIMBBAIRwwwjwB8ACgCUAbgCwAKGkBJAARUMAeTwxGs4SPl0AFjFjyFII5wCGAZxgBVAJayMMALbSA3tPmfPAAQDs8whgAMzMcABsMMXkAemihWREhNTp5bl5+UXFpAF9pDwUleiZNUR19Q2NTSxt7RxcpdykvTwhgACsYMAx5IPkAXnlk1J4+PFFJJua/eXiRIIncqW8AZnlvACZ5Vg400fkTAGF+DCgIMPMrNFMR/jdF6RX5WzxHKBCwGCqrOwdnO7ylqtnq93p9ZLt+PsvjVfvVXPdAWtNkcXqdztUoeDqj86v8ZIiNsN0ngoSiTmcLjAruCbng8dIgA):

```cs
GetTwo<NotAButton>();
```

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Button' to type 'NotAButton'.

If you want to be able to create a new instance of your generic you can use `new` [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

```cs
I GetOne<I>() where I : IBaseUiItem, new()
{
     return new();
}
```

Comment: So my mistake was I thought by restricting using:
`: where I: IBaseUiItem`
I was telling the compiler, I could pass only an interface to the generic...
which is not the case. This is not the restriction that I wanted.
The actual body of the method is different. It looks into a dictionary for the given type and creates an instance of the (only) class which implements this interface.

Comment: @alternator even if you could restrict it to only interfaces this would not fix anything for the same reason.

Comment: Because I is not guaranteed to be Button (or any interface which inherits IBaseUiItem 
Would not agree. If this was an "interface restriction" and I cannot call GetOne<> with a type an interface which is not IBaseUiItem, what's wrong when I try to return something which implements such an interface?
My idea is to call that method like: GetOne<IButton>()

Comment: So the restriction doesn't give you a chance to ask for another interface and I am returning an instance of an object which could be fast to such an interface. I understand the example with NotAButton, but we started to speak about a thing that does not exist.
If Everything was only about the interface the compiler would be able to check and even produce correct code.
But I made wrong assumption. So no point to continue that part of the discussion. Will mark you answer as correct.